# Core Graphics angle gradient for gauge

Tags: ios, core-graphics, gradient, angle, gauge

I'm trying to apply an angle gradient to the dashes created with the code I've written inside a custom UIView class, as below. Although it needs tweaking, I'm happy with the results it produces so far.

Given the input parameters in the view initialisation (below), and a frame of 768 * 768 on an iPad Air2 in portrait mode, it produces the following gauge:

[First gauge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QX5Zd.jpg)

What I'd like to do is to cause each of the dashes to step through a user-defined gradient, e.g. green to red, much like this (kludged in Photoshop):

[Gauge with colours](https://i.stack.imgur.com/97MCA.jpg)

I've searched high and low, and cannot find anything to achieve this. The only things that come close use different drawing methods, and I want to keep my drawing routine.

As far as I'm concerned, I should simply be able to call:

CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(myContext, [gradient color goes here])

inside the draw loop, and that's it, but I don't know how to create the relevant color array/gradient, and change the line drawing color according to an index into that array.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    myContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    UIImage *gaugeImage = [self radials:300 andSteps:3 andLineWidth:10.0];
    UIImageView *gaugeImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:gaugeImage];
    [self addSubview:gaugeImageView];

}

-(UIImage *)radials:(NSInteger)degrees andSteps:(NSInteger)steps andLineWidth:(CGFloat)lineWidth{

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.bounds.size);
    myContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetLineWidth(myContext, lineWidth);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(myContext, [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor]);

    CGPoint center = CGPointMake(self.bounds.origin.x+(self.bounds.size.width/2), self.bounds.origin.y+(self.bounds.size.height/2));
    CGFloat r1 = center.x * 0.87f;
    CGFloat r2 = center.x * 0.95f;

    CGContextTranslateCTM(myContext, center.x, center.y);
    CGContextBeginPath(myContext);

    CGFloat offset  = 0;

    if(degrees < 360){
        offset = (360-degrees) / 2;
    }

    for(int lp = offset + 0 ; lp < offset + degrees+1 ; lp+=steps){

        CGFloat theta = lp * (2 * M_PI / 360);
        CGContextMoveToPoint(myContext, 0, 0);

        r1 = center.x * 0.87f;
        if(lp % 10 == 0){
            r1 = center.x * 0.81f;
        }

        CGContextMoveToPoint(myContext, sin(theta) * r1, cos(theta) * r1);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(myContext, sin(theta) * r2, cos(theta) * r2);
        CGContextStrokePath(myContext);
    }

    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return image;
}
```

Comment: Do not misuse `drawRect` like that. `drawRect` is for drawing — not for adding subviews. Remember, `drawRect` is called many times, and you'll just be adding that subview again and again, which is ridiculous.

Comment: Point taken! My mistake!

Answer (score 3):

So, you want something like this:

[image: rainbow gauge view]

First, a couple of gentle suggestions:

1. Don't add subviews inside `drawRect:`. What if `drawRect:` gets called a second time, if for example the view's size changes?

   Here's what the [*View Programming Guide for iOS*](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/CreatingViews/CreatingViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH5-SW3) says about implementing `drawRect:`:

   > The implementation of your `drawRect:` method should do exactly one thing: draw your content. This method is not the place to be updating your application’s data structures or performing any tasks not related to drawing. It should configure the drawing environment, draw your content, and exit as quickly as possible. And if your `drawRect:` method might be called frequently, you should do everything you can to optimize your drawing code and draw as little as possible each time the method is called.

   If you need to add or remove subviews, you should do that when the view is initialized, or in `layoutSubviews` at the latest.
2. There's no need to draw into an image or use an image view at all. The whole point of `drawRect:` is to draw into the current graphics context, which UIKit has already set up to target the view's backing store.

Those suggestions aside, there is no support for angular gradients in Core Graphics. However, for your graphic, you can set the color for each tick mark separately and get a pretty good approximation, which is how I created the image above. Use [`+[UIColor colorWithHue:saturation:brightness:alpha:]`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicolor/1621939-colorwithhue?language=objc) to create your color, calculating the hue parameter based on the tick angle.

If you factor out the drawing code into a separate class, it's easy to use it to draw either directly to a view (in `drawRect:`), or to an image if you need to. Here's the interface:

```
@interface RainbowGaugeAppearance: NSObject

@property (nonatomic) CGFloat startDegrees;
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat endDegrees;
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat degreesPerMajorTick;
@property (nonatomic) int subdivisionsPerMajorTick;
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat tickThickness;
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat startHue;
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat endHue;
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat outerRadiusFraction;
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat minorInnerRadiusFraction;
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat majorInnerRadiusFraction;

- (instancetype _Nonnull)init;
- (void)drawInRect:(CGRect)rect;
@end
```

And the implementation:

```
@implementation RainbowGaugeAppearance

static CGFloat radiansForDegrees(CGFloat degrees) { return degrees * M_PI / 180; }

- (instancetype _Nonnull)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        _startDegrees = 120;
        _endDegrees = _startDegrees + 300;
        _degreesPerMajorTick = 30;
        _subdivisionsPerMajorTick = 10;
        _tickThickness = 4;
        _outerRadiusFraction = 0.95;
        _minorInnerRadiusFraction = 0.87;
        _majorInnerRadiusFraction = 0.81;
        _startHue = 1/ 3.0;
        _endHue = 0;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawInRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef gc = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSaveGState(gc); {
        CGContextTranslateCTM(gc, CGRectGetMidX(rect), CGRectGetMidY(rect));
        CGContextSetLineWidth(gc, self.tickThickness);
        CGContextSetLineCap(gc, kCGLineCapButt);

        CGFloat outerRadius = _outerRadiusFraction / 2 * rect.size.width;
        CGFloat minorInnerRadius = _minorInnerRadiusFraction / 2 * rect.size.width;
        CGFloat majorInnerRadius = _majorInnerRadiusFraction / 2 * rect.size.width;

        CGFloat degreesPerTick = _degreesPerMajorTick / _subdivisionsPerMajorTick;
        for (int i = 0; ; ++i) {
            CGFloat degrees = _startDegrees + i * degreesPerTick;
            if (degrees > _endDegrees) { break; }

            CGFloat t = (degrees - _startDegrees) / (_endDegrees - _startDegrees);
            CGFloat hue = _startHue + t * (_endHue - _startHue);
            CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(gc, [UIColor colorWithHue:hue saturation:0.8 brightness:1 alpha:1].CGColor);

            CGFloat sine = sin(radiansForDegrees(degrees));
            CGFloat cosine = cos(radiansForDegrees(degrees));
            CGFloat innerRadius = (i % _subdivisionsPerMajorTick == 0) ? majorInnerRadius : minorInnerRadius;
            CGContextMoveToPoint(gc, outerRadius * cosine, outerRadius * sine);
            CGContextAddLineToPoint(gc, innerRadius * cosine, innerRadius * sine);
            CGContextStrokePath(gc);
        }
    } CGContextRestoreGState(gc);
}

@end
```

Using it to draw a view is then trivial:

```
@implementation RainbowGaugeView {
    RainbowGaugeAppearance *_appearance;
}

- (RainbowGaugeAppearance *_Nonnull)appearance {
    if (_appearance == nil) { _appearance = [[RainbowGaugeAppearance alloc] init]; }
    return _appearance;
}

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [self.appearance drawInRect:self.bounds];
}

@end
```

Comment: Great.

Again, SO advise not to make comments like 'thanks', but what else can I say!

Comment: If the answers posted here have helped you, please upvote them. Also click the check mark next to the the most helpful answer to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

> As far as I'm concerned, I should simply be able to call CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor

Reality, however, is not interested in "as far as you're concerned". You are describing an angle gradient. The reality is that there is no built-in Core Graphics facility for creating an angle gradient.

However, you can do it easily with a good library such as [AngleGradientLayer](https://github.com/paiv/AngleGradientLayer). It is then a simple matter to draw the angle gradient and use your gauge drawing as a *mask*.

In that way, I got this — *not* kludged in Photoshop, but done entirely live, in iOS, using AngleGradientLayer, plus your `radials:andSteps:andLineWidth:` method just copied and pasted in and used to generate the mask:

[image]

Here's the only code I had to write. First, generating the angle gradient layer:

```
+ (Class)layerClass {
    return [AngleGradientLayer class];
}
- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:coder];
    if (self) {
        AngleGradientLayer *l = (AngleGradientLayer *)self.layer;
        l.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
           (id)[UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1].CGColor,
           (id)[UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:1 blue:0 alpha:1].CGColor,
           nil];
        l.startAngle = M_PI/2.0;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Second, the mask (this part is in Swift, but that's irrelevant):

```
let im = self.v.radials(300, andSteps: 3, andLineWidth: 10)
let iv = UIImageView(image:im)
self.v.mask = iv
```

Comment: Excellent.

SO say not to use comments like 'thanks', but I have no idea why, so thank you for a simple solution and for the lesson.

Comment: The problem with `AngleGradientLayer` is that it interpolates a linear path through RGB space. That's why the yellow and orange here looks so muddy. Interpolating through HSB space usually gives better results.

Comment: Also, Max, be aware that you will have to update the `mask` view's frame if the gauge view is resized, because neither auto layout nor autoresizing affect a view's `mask`.

Comment: @robmayoff Which is something I've wondered about ever since they introduced view masks. They are cool in that at least they can easily be self-drawing, but without participation in layout of subviews, how are they _really_ any better than layer masks?

Comment: Yeah it's a really annoying oversight on Apple's part.

Comment: Yes, thanks again for the pointers, Rob and Matt.

Both your code examples are so much more elegant than mine, and I've learned a lot just by reaching out on here, and putting my amateur efforts up for scrutiny and direction.

Comment: But Rob is suggesting that you should _accept_ one of them (his). And I agree. Both of us did a _lot_ of work to write our answers. To accept neither of them, if either helped you, seems (in my view) rude. Acceptance of answers is the "money" of the Stack Overflow world; it is _how_ you show gratitude. That is why you are not supposed to write "thank you" comments. You show thanks by upvoting and accepting.