# Gradient Color over Template Image in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage

I am trying to make a chat app in my application using swift 4.

I want the chat bubble to appear with gradient color That I set programatically.

I Achieved That by a solid color by rendering the image as template as the following:

```
    let TestImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 200))
    let TestImage = ChatBubble
    let TestImage2 = TestImage.resizableImage(withCapInsets: TestInsets, resizingMode: .stretch).withRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.alwaysTemplate)
    TestImageView.image = TestImage2
    TestImageView.tintColor = UIColor.red
```

How to do it?

Update: I made it by Mr.Matt solution but I went through some troubles in sizing. This is my Final Code after Making it inside a class:

class UIChatBubbleView: UIView {

```
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    let ChatBubbleView = UIImageView(frame: rect)
    let BubbleInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 100, left: 200, bottom: 240, right: 240)
    let BubbleImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "ChatBubble").resizableImage(withCapInsets: BubbleInsets, resizingMode: .stretch)
    ChatBubbleView.image = BubbleImage
    let MyView = UIView(frame: ChatBubbleView.bounds)
    MyView.layer.contents = ChatBubbleView.image?.cgImage
    let GradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    GradientLayer.frame = ChatBubbleView.bounds
    GradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.red.cgColor,UIColor.blue.cgColor]
    GradientLayer.mask = ChatBubbleView.layer

    MyView.layer.addSublayer(GradientLayer)
    MyView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    MyView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 3.0, height: 3.0)
    MyView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
    MyView.layer.shadowRadius = 3
    self.addSubview(MyView)
}

override init(frame:CGRect) {
    super.init(frame:frame)
    self.isOpaque = false
}
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

}

The final result appeared like this:

[image: Masked Gradient]

I want the gradient bubble size to be exactly as the black one.

Comment: Draw the gradient and mask it.

Comment: (See for example my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23202718/341994)

Comment: by what I will mask it?

Comment: By the chat bubble shape. (Exactly as, in the linked answer, the gradient is masked by the bezier path shape.)

Comment: Sorry, But the chat bubble is a PNG Image. how to make a shape from it?

Comment: The PNG image _is_ the shape. Use it as the mask.

Comment: Give me the code plz.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a "give me the codez" site. You write the code. We help. Besides, I linked you to an answer that shows actual code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Draw the gradient (a CAGradientLayer is the easiest way). Then use your bubble shape to mask the gradient.

For example, here's a sample bubble shape:

[image]

Here's that shape masking a red-to-orange gradient:

[image]

Now you can put your text inside the bubble (as a label, a CATextLayer, or whatever is convenient).

Comment: Ok Thanks, I will search for the code of how to convert an Image to mask that can applied as a CAShapeLayer to the CAGradientLayer. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: There's nothing to convert. All I did was use the bubble shape image in an image view as the mask for the view containing the gradient layer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, What made me confuse here is to try to make a CAShapeLayer from the provided image as your answer in the linked post. But now I figured out that I Must Create a Mask by a CALayer and make its contents the bubbleImage.cgimage and then masking the gradient layer and add it only to the sublayer of the chatbubble not also the Mask layer your post. However I was very far from making it without your help. Thanks Again.

Comment: No problem, although what I did was even simpler than that. :) Because, as I said, a view itself can have a `mask` which is another view. So I used a UIImageView holding the bubble as the view `mask`.

Comment: Tried that now and worked as a charm, and it is better than the old solution because it preserve the content scaling of the original UIImageView.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158334/discussion-between-famousmaxy-and-matt).

Comment: @Tometoyou I've given examples of how to mask a gradient so many times... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23202228/how-to-fill-a-uibezierpath-with-a-gradient/23202718#23202718 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42035746/core-graphics-angle-gradient-for-gauge/42036390#42036390 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53934686/ios-circular-gradient/53935318#53935318, I could go on and on.