# iOS Circular Gradient

Tags: ios, swift

I have a task to draw the line with a circular gradient (colour should change by the circle) and then add animation. Now I draw 360 layers with a certain interval and different colours.

```
var colours: [UIColor] = [UIColor]()
var startAngle = CGFloat(-0.5 * Double.pi)
var index = 0

func drawLayers() {
    let smallAngle = (1.5 * CGFloat.pi - (-0.5 * CGFloat.pi)) / 360

    if index < colours.count { //colours.count = 360
        let endAngle = startAngle + smallAngle
        let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: .init(x: 100, y: 100), radius: 100, startAngle: startAngle, endAngle: endAngle, clockwise: true)
        startAngle = endAngle
        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.path = circlePath.cgPath

        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = colours[index].cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 8

        view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)

        index += 1

        Timer.scheduledTimer(
            withTimeInterval: 0.004,
            repeats: false) { (_) in
                self.drawLayers()
        }
    }
}
```

Something like that but with linear animation

[image]

Can anyone tell me how to do it right?

Comment: @Rob 360 layers is hardly “fine”.

Comment: iOS has circular (conic) gradients built in now. So I would just ask for the gradient, once, and then animate a single path used as a mask. That’s just two layers, much less work, and a true gradient.

Comment: btw, your small angle can be simplified to `(2 * CGFloat.pi) / 360` (or 2 degrees).

Answer (score 6):

iOS has circular (conic) gradients built in now. So I would just ask for the gradient, once, and then animate a single path used as a mask. That’s just two layers, much less work, true animation, and a true gradient.

Example:

[image]

Here's my test code; change the colors and numbers as desired:

```
    let grad = CAGradientLayer()
    grad.type = .conic
    grad.colors = [UIColor.red.cgColor, UIColor.green.cgColor, UIColor.red.cgColor]
    grad.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
    grad.frame = CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 200, height: 200)
    self.view.layer.addSublayer(grad)
    let c = CAShapeLayer()
    let p = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: 160, height: 160))
    c.path = p.cgPath
    c.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    c.strokeColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    c.lineWidth = 8
    grad.mask = c
    c.strokeEnd = 0
```

To make the animation happen, just say:

```
    c.strokeEnd = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it is not what I looking for. Color should change by circle.

Comment: @DimaPaliychuk just FWIW, (A) if you want "more colors" in the circle (your example features seven), simply put more in the third line of code here. (B) if you want the color-gradient to "stretch" as the animation grows, the easiest way is to become familiar with the `.locations` property (basically squish it - simply multiply each number in `.locations` by the current fraction).